# Getting wrong output when converting iterator to integer for "lower_bound"

Tags: c++, stl, lower-bound

i was trying these 2 methods to convert an iterator into an index (int value), but i don't know why i am getting wrong output when i find an iterator using the "lower_bound" method, this works fine for the "find" method 
in the below snippet, when i use "find" method for x=4 i get 7(which is correct), but for "lower_bound" method on x=4, i am getting 2

```cpp
    vector<int> v = {5, 3, 7, 1, 2, 9, 8, 4, 6, 0};
    int x = 4;
    auto it = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), x);
    int index = distance(v.begin(), it);
    int i = it - v.begin();
    cout << index << " " << i;
```

Comment: `v` must be sorted before using `lower_bound`

Comment: btw, you don't need to convert to `int` to get the wrong result